# strange side stripes in uitableviewcell

Tags: uitableview

I am trying to create grouped table view and whenever I choose an alpha which is less then 1, I get those two weird stripes. Any suggestions? Thanks ahead.

Here is a screen shot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nyU.jpg

Answer (score 0):

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, once you have your cell, do:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```